# How to run a cron job?

Tags: linux, unix, cron, perl

I have a sample perl script which i need to run using cron daily ,could any one let me know the exact syntax to use cron job.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

To edit/view your crontab, type the following commands:

```
crontab -e # to edit
crontab -l # to view
```

Your cron job looks like as follows:

```
1 2 3 4 5 /path/to/command
```

Where 1 = minutes (0-59), 2 = hours (0-23), 3 = day (0-31), 4 = month (1-12), 5 = day of week (0-7).

For example, if I want to run something 5min after midnight, every day:

```
5 0 * * * /path/to/command
```

You can also specify multiple values, separated by commas or hyphens, such as:

```
5,10 0-2 * * * /path/to/command
```

which runs at 00:05, 00:10, 01:05, 01:10, 02:05 and 02:10 each day.

Comment: In what bizarro universe do years have 13 months? :-) I'm voting it up anyway and fixing it (and adding the fact that you can specify multiple values like 0,15,30,45 for minute).

Comment: Why would you ever want something to run at 00:05, 00:10, 01:05, 01:10, 02:05 and 02:10 each day? Surely you could provide a more useful example.

Answer (score 5):

best link newbie http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/

Comment: That's Linux-specific.  Non-Linux systems don't support all of those extensions like */4 or @monthly.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you should probably read `man 1 crontab` (for the usual command for interacting with your crontabs) and `man 5 crontab` (for the format they're written in) on your server.  The syntax of cron jobs is extensive and flexible, and without some specific objective in mind we're just going to wind up summarizing the man pages.

Answer (score 3):

[`man crontab`](http://ss64.com/bash/crontab.html)

Comment: Terse.

Comment: For me, this the best answer: if you just remember not to look at "cron" but "crontab" then you'll find a good description of what to do there.

Comment: If you forgot "crontab" and only remember "cron", try this: 'man -k cron'

Answer (score 2):

http://cronwtf.github.com/ is something I find useful when I inevitably forget the syntax.

Comment: Appears to be Linux-specific, although Linux supports all of the standard formats, so it might not be much of a problem here given the nature of this site.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want it to run daily and don't really care when it runs, you can just drop a shell script into /etc/cron.daily (this will also run it as root).  Otherwise, use crontab as suggested numerous times above.

Comment: depends on what OS and what version of cron.  not all support the /etc/cron.daily, /etc/cron.weekly, /etc/cron.monthly directories.  all linux dists do, but there's still a few non-linux unix boxes out there in the wild :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a click n easy graphical interface, you might want to try webmin http://www.webmin.com/

Otherwise "crontab -e" would do

Comment: You install webmin. Now you have two problems.

Comment: Webmin is almost a decent suggestion - except it doesn't answer his question.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above answers should be good, just a quick addition is that back ticks do not work well in cronjob entries. If you have to do things like `date +%Y%m%d`, you are better off just writing a script and calling that script from your cronjob.