# How to run a daily cron job? [nginx]

Tags: ubuntu, php, nginx, cron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run a cron job?](https://serverfault.com/questions/58251/how-to-run-a-cron-job)

```
Server: nginx/0.8.54
OS: Ubuntu 11.04
Host: Rackspace UK Cloud
Access: Full Root etc
```

I have a PHP script in my cloud server:

```
/var/www/www.site.com/web/cron_tasks.hash/report.php
```

I want to run this task every day just once - the time does not matter. It would be ideal if I could run it in the morning.

Also how can I view a list of already listed cron jobs? Sorry but I can't find an Nginx server question for this.

Comment: I think normal SSH commands will work regardless. Nginx btw is the server OS - it is a web server and not the server itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Open Nginx in SuperUser mode

  `sudo su`
- View Cron Jobs

  `crontab -l`
- Edit Cron Jobs

  `crontab -e`
- Daily Cron Jobs

  `# Run this script at 12 midnight once a day`

  `5 0 * * * /var/www/www.site.com/web/cron_tasks.hash/report.php`

Comment: This presupposes that the report.php has a suitable shebang which isn't normally the case.

Comment: Hi, may i know what does 5 0 * * * refers to?

Answer (score 1):

This really has nothing to do with nginx.

You can use the [crontab(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab) command to maintain user [crontab(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) files e.g.

```
crontab -u root -l
```

would list the entries in root's crontab. You would need to do this for each useron your system to get a complete list.

There will also be a /etc/crontab file that will contain system cron commands. The directories /etc/cron.* will contain additional commands too.

You'll probably find this [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) usefull at this point.

To run your command add an entry to a suitablBe user crontab like so

```
10 4 * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/www.site.com/web/cron_tasks.hash/report.php
```

Which will run the command at 04:10 every day